# How can I whitelist (blacklist?) destinations on a global OpenVPN connection?

Tags: networking, openvpn, networkmanager, vpn

I have imported a vendor-provided OVPN file into Network Manager. It acts globally, routing *all* requests through the VPN connection. This can be a problem with:

- geoblocked websites that also block VPN vendors (e.g. Netflix)
- captive portals (typically HTTP-without-S attempts that must resolve on the local network, not through the VPN)

How can I whitelist these addresses, so that they are resolved directly rather than through the VPN? (All other arbitrary addresses should still resolve through the VPN.)

Comment: Have a look at *policy routing* (google). Or, if your use case is simple enough, plain routing may already be enough.